# When taking the Martial Study feat as a Warblade, can I select from non-Warblade disciplines?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

When I am taking the Martial Study feat as a Warblade at 6th lvl, can I choose a maneuver from non-Warblade disciplines? For example, take a maneuver from the Desert Wind discipline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. When you do, it will be added as a warblade maneuver, that is, you must ready it as one of your warblade maneuvers readied, and you will recover it along with your other readied maneuvers when you use a swift action and then attack (or use a swift and a standard).

Comment: Site note, Desert Wind is generally considered the weakest discipline because fire damage is so frequently resisted. It’s still pretty good and there are definitely maneuvers worth taking from it, but just something to keep in mind.

Comment: ok. but if maneuver have prerequisite , example "one Desert wind maneuver", I cant take it?

Comment: @user1195154 you must still meet all prerequisites of the Maneuver chosen with this feat (also including your Initiator level). If you don't already have a Desert Wind maneuver (e.g. from taking Martial Study before), you can not select a maneuver that requires you to have one Desert Wind maneuver.

Comment: @user1195154 It may be worth discussing with your DM whether those prerequisites are actually adding anything to your game. Many tables find them obnoxious to track and pointless in any event; you don’t get enough maneuvers known where it really makes a difference, and it’s really awkward for those who take prestige classes. The halved Initiator Level is more than sufficient for Martial Study and non-initiators.